Here is a "good-bot" whitelist for my apache htaccess file. Is anything missing? I don't have time to maintain a bad-bot blacklist
I am trying to create a good-bot whitelist for my apache htaccess file, because I don't have enough time to maintain a constantly-expanding bad-bot blacklist.
However, I want to be careful not to block any legitimate visitors, search engines, browsers, or bots. So I have created the following htaccess code, with the help of AI. Will it block any legitimate traffic? Will it block bad bots?
I realize that I would have to update this occasionally to include any new legitimate sources of traffic.
Any advice would be much appreciated, but please answer in simple terms, as my knowledge of servers is very limited.
Here is the code:
# Enable RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On

# Security Headers
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header set Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"

# Prevent directory listing
Options -Indexes

# Whitelist: Allow All Known Browsers, Search Engines, and Good Bots

## Is it a Known Browser? The AND logical operator is implied
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Mozilla.*        [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Opera.*          [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*OPR.*            [NC]    # Opera's newer UA
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Msie.*           [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Firefox.*        [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*FxiOS.*          [NC]    # Firefox for iOS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Netscape.*       [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Safari.*         [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Edge.*           [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Edg.*            [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Chrome.*         [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*CriOS.*          [NC]    # Chrome for iOS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Brave.*          [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Vivaldi.*        [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Seamonkey.*      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Konqueror.*      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Iceweasel.*      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*UCBrowser.*      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Maxthon.*        [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*YaBrowser.*      [NC]     # Yandex Browser
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Midori.*         [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Avant.*          [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*QQBrowser.*      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*CocCoc.*         [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Sogou.*          [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Baidu.*          [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*SamsungBrowser.* [NC]    # Samsung Browser
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*MiuiBrowser.*    [NC]    # Xiaomi Browser

## Allow All Known Search Engine Bots
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Googlebot.*      [NC]    # Google
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Bingbot.*        [NC]    # Bing
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Slurp.*          [NC]    # Yahoo
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*DuckDuckBot.*    [NC]    # DuckDuckGo
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*YandexBot.*      [NC]    # Yandex
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Exabot.*         [NC]    # Exalead
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*facebot.*        [NC]    # Facebook
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*ia_archiver.*    [NC]    # Internet Archive
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*AhrefsBot.*      [NC]    # Ahrefs
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*SemrushBot.*     [NC]    # SEMrush
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*BLEXBot.*        [NC]    # BLEXBot
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*DotBot.*         [NC]    # Dotbot
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Mediapartners-Google.* [NC] # Google AdSense
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Baiduspider.*    [NC]    # Baidu
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*MojeekBot.*      [NC]    # Mojeek
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*PetalBot.*       [NC]    # Huawei Search
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Mail.RU_Bot.*    [NC]    # Mail.ru
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*GibiruBot.*      [NC]    # Gibiru
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Gigabot.*        [NC]    # Gigablast
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*BraveBot.*       [NC]    # Brave Search
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*QwantBot.*       [NC]    # Qwant
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*StartpageBot.*   [NC]    # Startpage
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*EcosiaBot.*      [NC]    # Ecosia
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*SwiftBot.*       [NC]    # Swisscows
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*MetaBot.*        [NC]    # MetaGer
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*SearchEncrypt.*  [NC]    # Search Encrypt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*WolfBot.*        [NC]    # WolframAlpha
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*OscoboBot.*      [NC]    # Oscobo
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*LookseekBot.*    [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*NeevaBot.*       [NC]    # Neeva
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*PeekBot.*        [NC]    # Seekport
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*YacyBot.*        [NC]    # YaCy
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*FindxBot.*       [NC]    # Findx
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*MeiliBot.*       [NC]    # Meilisearch
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*SphinxBot.*      [NC]    # Sphinx
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*SeznamBot.*      [NC]    # Seznam
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*CocCocBot.*      [NC]    # C?c C?c
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Linguee.*        [NC]    # Linguee
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*PresearbotBot.*  [NC]    # Presearch
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*KrakeBot.*       [NC]    # Kagi
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*WebCrawler.*     [NC]    # WebCrawler
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*DeuSu.*          [NC]    # DeuSu
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*GigablastOpenSource.* [NC] # Gigablast OpenSource

## is it a known Good bot or Service?
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*MJ12bot.*        [NC]    # Majestic
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Twitterbot.*     [NC]    # Twitter
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*LinkedInBot.*    [NC]    # LinkedIn
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Pinterest.*      [NC]    # Pinterest
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Slackbot.*       [NC]    # Slack
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*WhatsApp.*       [NC]    # WhatsApp
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*TelegramBot.*    [NC]    # Telegram
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Discordbot.*     [NC]    # Discord
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*SkypeUriPreview.* [NC]   # Skype
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Applebot.*       [NC]    # Apple
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*redditbot.*      [NC]    # Reddit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Nimbostratus.*   [NC]    # Tumblr
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Datadog.*        [NC]    # Datadog Monitoring
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*APIs-Google.*    [NC]    # Google API
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Google-Read-Aloud.* [NC] # Google Read Aloud
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*W3C_Validator.*  [NC]    # W3C Validator
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*GTmetrix.*       [NC]    # GTmetrix
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*PageSpeed.*      [NC]    # Google PageSpeed
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*WebPageTest.*    [NC]    # WebPageTest
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*StatusCake.*     [NC]    # StatusCake
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*UptimeRobot.*    [NC]    # UptimeRobot
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*NewRelic.*       [NC]       # New Relic 

## Social Media Preview Bots
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*facebookexternalhit.* [NC] # Facebook
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Mastodon.*      [NC]    # Mastodon
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*TumblrBot.*     [NC]       # Tumblr 

## Mobile App Webviews
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Instagram.*      [NC]    # Instagram in-app browser
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*FB_IAB.*         [NC]    # Facebook in-app browser
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*FBAN.*           [NC]    # Facebook app
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Twitter.*        [NC]    # Twitter in-app browser
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*LinkedInApp.*    [NC]       # LinkedIn app 

# If none of the above conditions are satisfied, then forbid the visitor
RewriteRule .* - [F]


# Protect against SQL injections – This is possibly error-prone, so I won’t include it.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "(?:declare|insert|drop|delete|update|union|select|create|rename|truncate|alter|exec|concat|print|or|and|varchar|where|join|into|load_file|outfile)" [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]

# Block empty User Agents and known bad bots
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$                 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^curl.*              [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^wget.*              [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Postman.*           [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Python.*            [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]

# Block access to sensitive files
<FilesMatch "^(\.htaccess|\.htpasswd|\.git|\.env|wp-config\.php)$">
    Order Allow, Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>


With a goodbot list like this, why even bother?    (ie I'm suggesting that many of the things you consider good bots many would consider bad bots, and most of the other bad bots will just fake being a version of chrome, mozilla or safari anyway.)

I think this is silly and a waste of time.  Why are you doing it?  Have any bad bots affected your site or GSE rankings?

@rohitgupta I think that is a bit harsh and partially disagree - considering bots can be useful as a small part of a more in depth strategy blocking some low hanging fruit. For example, blocking the mozlila (deliberate misspelling) blocks a number of automated  hacking attempts.  I think blocking bots is more about managing security and possibly load/traffic then Google rankings (of-course though a successfully hacked site can tank your google ratings...)

@rohitgupta  A few years ago, I inserted into my htaccess file a list of about 1500 bad bots, but I never got around to updating that list. I was too busy. Also, I read that bad bots can get past a blacklist by imitating good bots. So it seems that blacklists are not very effective, yet they require frequent maintenance.
A whitelist is probably no more effective, but at least it would not need to be updated as frequently. That's why I have resorted to creating a whitelist. But I realize I should not rely on it. On the other hand, if it blocks a few bad bots, then it's better than nothing.


"I want to be careful not to block any legitimate visitors, search
engines, browsers, or bots. So I have created the following htaccess
code, with the help of AI. Will it block any legitimate traffic? Will
it block bad bots?"

This is a really bad approach - and you should not be asking for the help of AI with something like this (arguably with anything you don't already have a strong idea of).
I argue that user agents are trivial to fake making this approach inaffective - it is something that the browser sends to the web server.   Bot can program this to reflect whatever they like, so it does not offer any protection from many malicious bots.  Indeed most of the malicious bots (ie automated hacking) I see come from "Mozilla" user agents.
Although what constitutes a bad bot is subjective, some of the bots you have accepted I specifically tag as bad bots.   Unless you are doing business in Russia for example, l.RU_Bot and Yandex are bots which are likely unhelpful.  You have similar bots for China on your list - and that is before you have decided on a policy of letting AI slurp your/your clients IP without providing anything in return.
Similarly, curl, wget and python have a lot of legitimate usage cases - so is blocking them really a good idea?

Not only are user agents trivial to fake, but pretty much every browser and a ton of bots use some Mozilla based user agent.  Just having Mozilla allows 99% of everything, both good and bad.

Okay, if user agents are trivial to fake, then bad bots can pretend to be good bots and thereby get past a whitelist. But if so, then surely by the same deception, bad bots can get past a blacklist too, right? If neither a whitelist nor a blacklist can block a bad bot in disguise, how then can I block bad bots?

@photon Correct. There is no easy solution to this problem.   At best you can say "potentially undesireable but legitimate bots can sometimes be blocked by agent string, as can some low hanging fruit - but user agents can't be reliably used to block bad bots.  A WAF (web application firewall) may be able to more reliably block bad actors - but there is no simple solution to the problem and your solution will wholly depend on your use case and goals.

@davidgo  Which WAFs would you recommend for a legacy bootstrap-3 website on an Apache server?

@Photon that is not something I can help you with. mod_security for Apache might be a starting point - but again, That said, isn't bootstrap just JavaScript and CSS? If so, what threat are you looking at? (I'm positing that it may be better to allow static content regardless of requester rather then add the complexity of a WAF.)

@davidgo Your point seems valid; maybe my website doesn't need protection. On the other hand, perhaps it could be hijacked to launch an attack on some other website. If that is at all possible, then I'd rather be safe than sorry. You have suggested mod_security, so I'll look into that, and see if it can be used without getting too complicated. Thanks!

Do you have any dynamic code (as in something that uses PHP or CGI or similar to execute code server side)?  If not, you are likely better off focussing securing your environment (ie locking down everything that is not needed - possibly only running Apache).   Similarly, are you running multiple virtualhosts or just 1?  If multiple virtualhosts, maybe look at how you can better enforce seperation and jails.    Its lower hanging fruit - but on a web page basis, I'd look more at directives to control cross-site scripting (XSS attacks) then worry about user agents...

ie your webserver is unlikely to be at threat from web requests if you are not running dynamic code - rather you may want to look out for your clients interest.  Relatedly, controlling advertising sources.

@davidgo  Yes, my website does have some php and js. I will read up on your suggestions. Thanks!
